# Umlauts and ordering nodes

Tags: 7, views

I'm using views and I sort nodes by title. Now it works perfectly, but problem is that I have umlauts too and it doesn't recognise those. For example I have nodes with title "Dähne Mit" and "Dahne Ohne". The correct order of course would be:

```
Dahne Ohne
Dähne Mit
```

But now Drupal list them as:

```
Dähne Mit
Dahne Ohne
```

So Dähne becames before Dahne :/

Comment: Drupal doesn't do the ordering, your database engine does. Check the collation on your tables, it's probably wrong

Comment: It's the default utf8_general_ci. Can I change it? As I said, it's site that is live and it's a big one. Or can I change it just in this case somehow?

Comment: I wouldn't know (and this isn't the right place to find out). Start here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collation-effect.html, and consult a DB admin if you're not sure whether it's safe to change the collation while the site is live

Comment: But you don't think there is another way doing the ordering? With PHP somehow?

Comment: You could, I guess, but it would be quite inefficient, and probably more work than it's worth. Better to get your db configured properly than try to hack around the problem

Comment: It's not a Drupal question. You need to useutf8_unicode_ci in your database: http://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/5169597

Comment: There's no difference between using custom code and Views - the problem isn't at Drupal's end, it's in your database. See the link @ar7max posted, that contains everything you'll ever need to know about the subject (plus explains why there's no Drupal-related 'fix' to the issue)